# How to return int if whole number, while ignoring floats and strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take an input, which can be float or string, and if it's a whole number, return int(input), otherwise just return input.

So far i tried using excep ValueError but this didnt sem to work.

```
def whole_number(num): #takes float or str
    try:
        x = num%1
        if x == 0:
            return int(num)
        else:
            return num
    except ValueError:
        return num

print(whole_number(1.1)) #should return 1.1
print(whole_number(9.0)) #should return 9
print(whole_number("word")) #should return "word"
```

but keep getting the error "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want a string like `"123"` or `"-1"` to be converted to `int`, or returned unmodified? What about `"123.0"`/`"-1.0"`? What about `" 123.0 "`/`" -1 "` (with leading and trailing whitespace, which are seamlessly stripped by the `int`/`float` conversion functions)? What about `"1e10"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`float.is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) to check for whole numbers:

```
def whole_number(num): # takes float or str
    return int(num) if isinstance(num, float) and num.is_integer() else num
```

Sample **usage**:

```
>>> whole_number(1.1)
1.1
>>> whole_number(9.0)
9
>>> whole_number("word")
word
```

**What's wrong?**

```
num = 'word'
print(num%1)
```

..is the part your code fails. Using mod operation on string, Python considers it as an attempt to format string with`'%'` throwing *"TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"*.

Comment: This answer could be better if you explained why `num % 1` failed (I mention why in the comments, but I don't really want to post a separate answer just for that part).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, please edit to add more details if you have more.

Comment: @NoaG96, Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will help community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Comment: @Austin: Your addition was fine; up-voted. The old `printf`-style formatting usually doesn't cause problems, but this is one of those rare cases where duck typing is failing you; all three expected argument types support `%`, but one of them behaves very differently. I'm not sure this is a *complete* answer (strings are being ignored, and [it's unclear if numeric strings should be converted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57461666/how-to-return-int-if-whole-number-while-ignoring-floats-and-strings/57461738#comment101398295_57461666)), but for the rest of the question, it's good.